# How to remove index.php from url without getting 404 error in wp?

Tags: php, wordpress

I know that this problem has been mentioned hundreds of times, and that there are hundreds of web pages and YouTube channels that have provided a solution, but I tried everything and it did not work, here is the information about this problem:
1- WP Version 5.9.3

2- PHP 8.1.4 (cli) (built: Apr 4 2022 13:30:17) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.4, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v8.1.4, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

3-

```
$ sudo apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
Loaded Modules:
core_module (static)
so_module (static)
watchdog_module (static)
http_module (static)
log_config_module (static)
logio_module (static)
version_module (static)
unixd_module (static)
access_compat_module (shared)
alias_module (shared)
auth_basic_module (shared)
authn_core_module (shared)
authn_file_module (shared)
authz_core_module (shared)
authz_host_module (shared)
authz_user_module (shared)
autoindex_module (shared)
deflate_module (shared)
dir_module (shared)
env_module (shared)
filter_module (shared)
mime_module (shared)
mpm_prefork_module (shared)
negotiation_module (shared)
php_module (shared)
reqtimeout_module (shared)
rewrite_module (shared)
security2_module (shared)
setenvif_module (shared)
socache_shmcb_module (shared)
ssl_module (shared)
status_module (shared)
unique_id_module (shared)
```

==================

4- rewrite module:

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
Module rewrite already enabled
```

5-.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

6- Woocommerce plugin installed

7- Theme: Storefront

==================================

if I go Settings->Permalinks->Custom Structure: /index.php/%postname%/
every thing is working except of the legacy API but this is not my problem now.
if I go Settings->Permalinks->Custom Structure: /%postname%/
I will get 404 error for all links in home page.

==================================

so please help me

Comment: Is your server configured to read .htaccess files to begin with? Check the `AccessFileName` directive. And what `AllowOverride` is set to.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it, you have directed me to the right place to fix the error, now everything is working like a dream.